# Icon with text on text block

Tags: css, wordpress, icons

I'm new on WP and I need some advice on a task, I want something like this : [image]

So, in my block text I need an icon and a text associated to it (like in the image), but I don't know how to align them since currently I have this :

[image]

Here is my code : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure should look like this:

```
<div class='wrap'>
<img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/699049-icon-6-mail-envelope-closed-128.png" height=70 width=70 alt="mailIcon">
<span class="address">Mymail@provider.com</span>
</div>
```

The Css is in the link, keep in mind this is a single icon module using flexbox, I find this very practical, especially for mobile design.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/pRzBMp

I have added a horizontal and verticl aligment layout, they both look grand:-)

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how I do it in WP, like it's not just hard code :/, i've tried some stuff with the block code but I'm quite lost with it.

Comment: If it's WP, you just find the elements in dev tools and change the css:-) post the live site if possible, then folks can have a look

Comment: Finally find what I looked for. I needed the list with icon item but thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try this: `img style="vertical-align:middle"` in the img tag.